# Armenian and Khmer characters distort vertical text alignment in React Native / iOS

Tags: ios, text, react-native, internationalization, vertical-alignment

In my React Native app I wish to display amounts of money with the currency symbols of various countries, displayed vertically centered in its container.

This works fine with most currency symbols but some alter the vertical alignment of the entire text. So far the only ones that do this are the signs for Armenian Dram and Cambodian Riels.

I'm not currently able to test what happens on Android so can only state this happens on iOS.

Is this something I can address at either the React Native level or the iOS level?

[image: comparison of three symbols]

Answer (score 0):

I've made a test rendering 3 texts in different lines, like this

```
<Text>&#1423;100</Text>
<Text>$100</Text>
<Text>&#6107;100</Text>
```

They all seems to have the same style. Try to use these codes to generate your currency icon and check if isn't there any style (like `lineHeight`) applied to your component.

Hope it helps.